# How to manually select options in Angular using JS in console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation

As part of a browser automation, I need to hook into the Angular app from the browser console (without automation tools) and manually select the desired “state” and “city” from two drop down lists. I have successfully `dirty` the input forms (e.g. username field) by JavaScript code before but I couldn’t automate the drop down selection.

I have tried to set the `$viewValue`, `$modelValue`, `$$rawModelValue` and `$$lastCommittedViewValue` to `states` object and then trigger the `$digest` using `$scope.$apply()`  and `controller("ngModel").$render()`. But I couldn’t successfully update the changes to the `$scope`. Once I execute the `$apply()` function, the state and city values are cleared from the view. I don’t have access to the Angular source code and the web page is IP restricted and unfortunately isn't publicly available. But I have uploaded the `$scope` JSON file [here](https://jsonblob.com/84ac7a86-ff3b-11e9-8b96-579c1486d35b) and also the HTML elements code and my JavaScript code in the snippet. There are two controls in `$scopeState.state.$$controls` that I think are related to the drop down list. I read about the Angular architecture and how Template and Directives and ngModel works but still couldn’t figure out how to manually select the options in this case. Can you please explain in details what is happening when we click on the drop down list? Which function or directive is in charge and how to do it using JavaScript in console?

```js
var myState = document.evaluate("//*[@id='state']", document).iterateNext();
var elNameState = angular.element(myState);
var $scopeState = elNameState.scope();
$scopeState.state.$$controls[state].$viewValue='{id: 20}';

var myCity = document.evaluate("//*[@id='city']", document).iterateNext();
var elNameCity = angular.element(myCity);
var $scopeCity = elNameCity.scope();
$scopeState.state.$$controls[city].$viewValue='{id: 5}';
```

**Update: The scope is updated now by changing the id and triggering the digest.**

Comment: Use [$setViewValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue).

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks. It works now.